# Chrome App fileSystem API: Suggested file name has no extension in OSX

Tags: javascript, macos, google-chrome, google-chrome-app

I have developed a Chrome App that works perfectly in both Linux, Windows and OSX. Except for one little thing:

In OSX the suggested file name has no extension. When the file is saved, the extension is omitted and the file can't be opened unless the user manually adds the extension.

I use code like this:

```
var config = {
    type: 'saveFile',
    suggestedName: "test.srt"
};
chrome.fileSystem.chooseEntry(config, function(writableEntry) {
    if(chrome.runtime.lastError) {
        console.warn(chrome.runtime.lastError.message);
    }
    else if (writableEntry) {
        var blob = new Blob([subtitles], {type: "text/srt"})
        writeFileEntry(writableEntry, blob, false, function(e) {
          console.log("Subtitles saved", writableEntry.fullPath);
        })
    }
});
```

Is that just the way it is in OSX or can I change anything to make it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a Chromium/Chrome bug: <s>[crbug issue 439857](https://crbug.com/439857)</s> (**fixed on 16 Dec 2015, Chrome 49**).

As for now try doubling the extension on OSX: `test.srt.srt`

Comment: Well, that's a crude fix as the file ends up with the double extension which looks kind of weird. But at least it gets recognized when double clicking etc. A somewhat better looking solution is to use a double dot, test..srt. But still hoping for a real solution!

Comment: The real solution would be to submit a patch into Chromium source code.

Comment: I agree. Unfortunately that is beyond my scope.

Comment: It looks like one googler take the issue. if it is not implemented in a month, then let me know. i can implement.

Comment: @SunggukLim: Thanks. Will do.

Comment: @SunggukLim: Just a friendly reminder. More than a month has passed and the issue is still present :-)

Comment: @marlar it is fixed now. you might be able to check with latest canary from tomorrow

Comment: Some installations of Chrome on OSX still have the problem. I have seen it on Chrome 62.0.3202.94.